# Scrollable div (overflow:hidden) with hover images

Tags: javascript, css, hover, overflow

I have a div with overflow:auto and a table inside. The div creates a vertical scroll bar as desired. However, I want to have a preview hover state for each row. This means that this hover state Div would have to go beyond the boundaries of the containing div. How would i do this with the overflow already set to hide my contents... z-index wont let me escape the parent.

Comment: Show us your code, what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a vertical scrollbar, then you can set to overflow-y:scroll and not set the overflow horizontally. Then just make sure your images only leaves the horizontal boundaries (not the verticals).

Next time, create a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/  and we can help you even faster :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to have the hover state be able to leave both the horizontal and vertical boundaries... Do you know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute;`and set the `z-index` to a visible value for the div that you wish to overflow its container.

Answer (score 0):

i recently resolved a similar issue, this should help you out:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383906/1063287

also see related jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/eeaAr/

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id ="hbar_one"></div>
<div id="hbar_two"></div>
<div id="container_a">
<div id="container_b">
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
some amazing html
</div>
</div>
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
more amazing html
</div>
</div>
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
even more amazing html
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hbar_three"></div>
<div id="hbar_four"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper {
width: 300px;   
}
#hbar_one {
background: #cc0000;   
height: 50px;
}

#hbar_two {
background: #ffcc00;   
height: 50px;
}

#container_b {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.hidden_db_data_div {
display: none;
background: #00AFF0;
width: 120px;
height: 150px;
color: red;
position:absolute;
overflow: hidden; 
z-index: 999;  
}

img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

.magic {
display: inline;
}

#container_a { position:relative; }

#hbar_three {
background: #cccccc;   
height: 50px;
}

#hbar_four {
background: #000000;   
height: 50px;
}
```

**script**

```
$(".magic").hover(
function () {
$(this)
.find('.hidden_db_data_div')
.css({'left':$(this).position().left+20 + "px", 'top':'-20px'})
.fadeIn(200);
},
function() { 
$(this)
.find('.hidden_db_data_div')
.fadeOut(100);
}                
);
```