# how to enforce hover state div is shown above other elements and outside of container?

Tags: css, hover

i've been going over this one for about two days.

**example**

it's a fairly complicated design, so to reduce code pasted here i've recreated the main structure on this jsfiddle and included the simplified code at the end of this post:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/zwxpG/10/

**scenario**

i have a container with numerous `<li>`'s containing a div (containing dynamic content from a database) that initially has the property display: none.

on hovering over an image in these `<li>`'s however, i wish to show the div.

it is working, however the div appears to be beneath other elements in the container which has a fixed height and overflow-y: auto.

**what i've tried**

i have tried combinations of z-index's and absolute and relative positioning, but i haven't been able to find a solution yet.

i've isolated two causes in the code below and the jsfiddle (shown as `/* comments */`) but these do not work on the live test site.

**question**

my question is therefore, is there another way to enforce that the hover state div is shown on top of and outside of the container that is enclosing it?

it is not an ideal solution that i can fix these issues in the jsfiddle but not the live site, but i just thought i'd ask if there was another way to approach this altogether?

thank you.

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id ="hbar_one"></div>
<div id="hbar_two"></div>
<div id="container_a">
<div  id="container_b">
<ul>
<li>
hover me #1
<div id="container_c">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In fringilla porttitor ante ut varius. Fusce volutpat velit ut orci porttitor cursus. Donec est eros, tempor ac elementum et, volutpat sit amet lorem. Mauris iaculis eros nec sapien hendrerit at sodales nibh iaculis. Morbi imperdiet porta est vitae suscipit. Curabitur sit amet diam in nulla consectetur placerat. Etiam in sapien ac mi scelerisque congue eu id lectus. Proin fermentum auctor turpis vel adipiscing. Maecenas at convallis sapien.
</div>
</li>
<li>
hover me #2
<div id="container_c">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In fringilla porttitor ante ut varius. Fusce volutpat velit ut orci porttitor cursus. Donec est eros, tempor ac elementum et, volutpat sit amet lorem. Mauris iaculis eros nec sapien hendrerit at sodales nibh iaculis. Morbi imperdiet porta est vitae suscipit. Curabitur sit amet diam in nulla consectetur placerat. Etiam in sapien ac mi scelerisque congue eu id lectus. Proin fermentum auctor turpis vel adipiscing. Maecenas at convallis sapien.
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hbar_three"></div>
<div id="hbar_four"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper {
 width: 300px;   
}
#hbar_one {
 background: #cc0000;   
 height: 50px;
}

#hbar_two {
 background: #ffcc00;   
 height: 50px;
}

#container_b {
    height: 50px;
/* cause one - on its own, this causes the undesired 'underneath' effect */
    overflow-y: auto;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
/* cause two - on its own, this causes the undesired 'underneath' effect */
    position: relative;   
}

#container_c {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover #container_c {
 background: #00AFF0;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position:absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: 50px; 
 z-index: 999;  
overflow: hidden;    
}

#hbar_three {
 background: #cccccc;   
 height: 50px;
}

#hbar_four {
 background: #000000;   
 height: 50px;
}
```

**update**

in response to answer below, here is further information on the actual content that is being displayed upon hover (everything within the `#container_c` div).  each `<li>` has its own unique content:

```
​<li class=".class1 .class2">
<img src="http://path/to/image.jpg">
<div id="container_c">
<h4>title</h4>
<div id="container_c_left">
<span id="cl1">text</span>
<span id="cl2">text</span>
<span id="cl3">text</span>
</div>
<div id="container_c_right">
<span id="cr1">text</span>
<span id="cr2">text</span>
</div>
<span id="cc1">text</span>
<span id="cc2"><a class= "linkclass" href="http://path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was a mixture of @NoPyGod's jquery suggestion and to have a better understanding of how absolute and relative positioning work.

basically, when absolute and relative positioning are applied to a div, this position is relative to the position of the last element that had absolute or relative positioning defined and is a 'container' of the div you are working with.

to escape from the 'container' that had overflow: auto and a fixed height and width, i had to remove erroneous positioning back till a parent div that was not constrained by overflow and height and width restraints that were impacting on the hover state div.

a working jsfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/eeaAr/

i also implemented @Deepak Kamat's suggestion to only have one id per page and change the rest of the div's to be identified by classes.

i subsequently read the article below that made more sense to me this time and after working in this context:

http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

thank you to all for your assistance!

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id ="hbar_one"></div>
<div id="hbar_two"></div>
<div id="container_a">
<div id="container_b">
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
some amazing html
</div>
</div>
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
more amazing html
</div>
</div>
<div class="class1 class2 magic" data-unique-content=".hidden_db_data_div">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/50/50/">
<div class="hidden_db_data_div">
even more amazing html
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="hbar_three"></div>
<div id="hbar_four"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper {
width: 300px;   
}
#hbar_one {
background: #cc0000;   
height: 50px;
}

#hbar_two {
background: #ffcc00;   
height: 50px;
}

#container_b {
height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.hidden_db_data_div {
display: none;
background: #00AFF0;
width: 120px;
height: 150px;
color: red;
position:absolute;
overflow: hidden; 
z-index: 999;  
}

img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

.magic {
display: inline;
}

#container_a { position:relative; }

#hbar_three {
background: #cccccc;   
height: 50px;
}

#hbar_four {
background: #000000;   
height: 50px;
}
```

**script**

```
$(".magic").hover(
function () {
$(this)
.find('.hidden_db_data_div')
.css({'left':$(this).position().left+20 + "px", 'top':'-20px'})
.fadeIn(200);
},
function() { 
$(this)
.find('.hidden_db_data_div')
.fadeOut(100);
}                
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to display one of these hover elements at a time?

Put a single DIV outside of the main body and make it hidden.

Then use javascript to adjust its position and content every time you hover over an LI.

No need to give every LI its own DIV.

Store the contents inside a data attribute

```
<li id=something data-some-content="Hello joe">
```

Then you can retrieve it with jQuery like so

```
$("#something").data('some-content')
```

Comment: thank you for this succinct approach, i have amended my post to include what is within the div that is displayed (see '***update***').  i am not sure whether your solution would work with this content as it contains html?  can `data-some-content="Hello Joe"` be `data-some-content="<img src="http://path/to/image.jpg"> + #container_c"`?  and in response to your question, yes i want to display one of these elements at a time upon hover, and each `<li>` holds unique content.  thank you.

Comment: You can do that, you'd just have to escape the html entities inside the data attribute. Alternatively, if the content will always be an image then you can just use data-img-location="http://someimage.gif". Or if it's an image and some text you could use one data attribute for the image and one for the text.

Comment: Sorry for the request for extra clarification - but can you please tell me the exact syntax for including an image and then a div in a data attribute (using the example in my comment above), i'm going to try this but want to make sure it is possible before i have a go! thank you!

Comment: i'm working on a jsfiddle with this concept here - any help appreciated, thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/eeaAr/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS styles are correct but in your HTML you have two `<div>` elements with the `id='container_c'` and that's invalid, IDs are unique and you can't give same id to two or more elements. If you two ore more elements to be given same style then try `class='container_c'` and in the CSS change the `#container_c`  to `.container_c`

Check this fiddle for the fixed version 
http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/zwxpG/13/

Comment: thank you very much for this information, in your fixed code the css contains .container_b (therefore a class), whereas the html refers to an id of container_b (which requires #container_b).  when i change the css to #container_b or change the html to match the css class reference unfortunately the solution does not work.  thank you.

Comment: Ohh I am sorry, I changed the #container_b selector to a class selector. But if you remove the `overflow-y:auto` from `#container_b`and that should work.

Comment: thank you, yes that solution was in the comments, but unfortunately does not work on the live site :(.